# Rapidly changing texture of a GL plane

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm dealing with large bitmaps (5000x1440, think dual, tripple monitors), which sometimes don't fit into the memory (heap) available to application (this is true for the parts which are developed in Java).

Native code in Android, though, is able to allocate as much as is available on the device (almost). The problem is, that one can't easily access this data as an `int[]` or something similart that would be fed to `Bitmap` class.

I got a hint that some OpenGL functions accept ByteBuffer parameters, so I've prototyped a solution, where I apply this image as a texture to an OpenGL plane.

Disclaimer: I'm a total GL noob, so this may be a stupid question

I'd like to rapidly change the texture data (as I'm getting an image over the wifi). If I just change the buffer contents, nothing happens.

If I load the texture on each `draw`, the app works, but soon many of the applications crash (I guess it is overloading the GL-ES or something, and Launcher, Google apps etc die and then restart). So it is obviously no good.

So, how to rapidly (frequently) change a texture in an efficient way?

Comment: How are you reloading the texture on each draw? E.g. is it possible you're generating a new texture each time and forgetting to `glDeleteTextures` on your old, causing them to accumulate?

Comment: I actually figured out how to not crash, though I'm not sure it is the correct way. Note that I have a static buffer whose contents are changing. On each draw, I call `gl.glTexImage2D` and I can see the changes being applied. As I said, I'm not sure if this is the way to go, even if the app does not crash now. In the final solution, I would call `glTexImage2D` only when changes would be necessary.

Comment: What sort of knowledge do you have about the changes? Are you able to switch to glTexSubImage2D and replace only intelligent subsections of the original?

Comment: Not at the moment. And even later, it depends on the protocol which can change in between. Do you think that calling glTexImage2D is too intensive for each change in the bitmap (texture)? I've done some tests in between and it runs pretty smooth with 4096x4096 texture. Most of CPU is taken by me manipulating this image in native code :).

Comment: `glTexImage2D` is traditionally 'expensive' compared to other GL ops but there's no other way to supply a full image so what you're really researching is feasibility. If it runs well enough on your actual hardware then that's pretty much the final word. If whatever is generating the data can do so in a more efficient format (like broadcast-TV quality YUV for 1.5 bytes/pixel) then you can reduce upload costs and unpack in a shader but if the full upload isn't a problem then it's not worth worrying about.